# TexShop will not compile after upgrade to Mac OS Monterey

Tags: errors

I just upgraded to Mac OS Monterey and when I attempt to LaTeX I get the following error

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
```

I had no problems compiling the same files before

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which version of MacOS were you using until just now?

Comment: That is not an error but the normal start message. Show the complete log-file of a small failing example.